# How to install an NPM server instance on an offline machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, npm, npm-install

I work in an offline network and I want to be able to type

```
npm install <package-name>
```

and then, a request to a local server inside my network will be sent to download the package.
What is the best way I can implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can setup local git server on your local network and store your package on local git server then you can install the package by

```
npm install https://gitserverip/user_name/package.git
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
It is possible to store all my packages in a repo and then install a specific one from it?

Comment: Yes . you can do that

Comment: If the repo contains the entire node_modules folder how can I tell npm to take only a specific one from it?

Comment: every package need separate repo

Comment: Isn't there a solution where I can download all my packages once on maybe a folder on the server, and then direct NPM to take one of the packages installed on that server (i.e. somehow create a unique URL for each package)?
I want to store a lot of packages, so creating a new git repo for each one of them manually it less optimal for me.

Comment: You can automate that with some crawler like puppeteer , selenium or you can use npm registry api . But end of the you did't get any update from package . you need to make server online . need to pull every changes from their repo. also I don't think storing npm in local system is not best option . If you need to setup custom npm registry you can follow https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-set-up-a-private-npm-registry-locally-1065e6790796 this documentation